# Как пронумеровать элементы списка

Tags: python

Как пронумеровать элементы списка, чтобы они были через двоеточие и с пробелом?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Пример:

```
list = ['apple','1','5']
for x,y in enumerate(list, start=1):
    print(f'{x}:{y}')
```

Comment: Не используйте зарезервированные слова Python в качестве названий переменных, у вас это `list`